# Cumulative Probability of winning a drawing with both multiple entries and multiple draws

Tags: probability

Recent Drawing: I own 8 tickets out of 273 tickets sold.  There will be 30 items given away.  I come up with a cumulative % of winning one of the items @89% (8/273 x 30).  Where did I go wrong...??

Comment: You found the expected number of prizes won.  This is not the same thing as the probability of having won at least one prize.  You found the right answer to the wrong question.  For an easier approach, consider the probability of having won nothing.

Answer (score 1):

- $243$ items won't be "prize-yielding"
- P(get no prize) $=\dfrac{\binom{243}8}{\binom{273}8} = x$, say
- Thus P(get at least one prize $= 1-x$

Comment: So what did 8 tickets get me...?  8 chances at @11% individually...? Meaning there's not a cumulative build up, only a series of individual draws(8) each one having @11% chance of winning....?

Comment: No, you get less, around 61%

Comment: What's the formula that gets me to 61%....?

Comment: That's what I gave in the answer ! $\;\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Comment: You could also do it as $ 1 - \frac{243}{273}\cdot\frac{242}{272}\cdot\frac{241}{271}\cdot \frac{240}{270}....\frac{236}{266}$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.  I appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome !$\;\;$:-)